# CSS class not working in a href

Tags: html, css

Working on a forum right now and the dimensions I gave to my a href and his children's are not working. When I debug it in the console in the browser they don't get the dimensions width and height I gave them in the CSS they are 0px 0px so there's probably a problem with my class named "forum-link" because his parent "child-forum" works perfectly. Thank you

HTML CODE

```
<div id="content">        
                <div class="forum-group">
                    <h2 class="header-2">General Discussion</h2>
                    <ul class="child-forums">
                        <li class="child-forum">
                        <a class="forum-link" href="#">
                            <span class="forum-icon"></span>
                            <span class="forum-details">
                                <span class="forum-title"></span>
                                <span class="forum-desc"></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
```

CSS CODE

```
.forum-group{
    width:948px;
    height:259px;    
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.header-2{
    width:948px;
    height:35px;
}
.child-forum{
    width:310px;
    height:106px;
    float:left;
    background-image: url(images/forum-child-background.jpg);
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
}
.child-forum:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
}
.child-forums{
    width:948px;height:219px;
}
.forum-link{
    width:309px;height:106px;    
}
.forum-icon{
    width:60px;height:60px;
}
.forum-details{
    width:220px;height:43px;
}
.forum-title{
    width:217px;height:18px;
}
.forum-desc{
    width:217px;height:15px;
}
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` tags are inline by default, and you cannot set width or height on inline elements.

To force it to be a block element, use one of these styles:

```
.forum-link {
  display: block;
}
```

… or

```
.forum-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Sure thing.  You could post your spans issue as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a position to your anchor tag in order for it to recognize `width` and `height`. You can do so by floating the link, `display:block` or `display:inline-block` whichever that fits your need.

```
a.forum-link {
    width:309px;
    height:106px;
    float:left;
}
```